# Other SIM cards won't work in VZW S5. Should I root it?

Tags: sim-card, verizon, t-mobile

I have a Verizon S5 which they claim to be unlocked. I travel internationally a lot and Verizon doesn't cover some of the places I go, so the Verizon rep I talked to said it's fine to just change out the SIM for a local one. I tried this in one country and it wouldn't recognize any local networks (or let me access the network selection menu for that matter). During my most recent trip back to the States I purchased a pre-paid T-Mobile SIM because it allegedly does work in these countries. However, upon installing the SIM I found that I only had voice/SMS capability (no data) and as soon as I left the US it stopped working entirely. The T-Mobile support couldn't even figure out what the issue was.

I have a sneaking suspicion that if I root the phone to get rid of the Verizon controls on it that it will magically start accepting other SIM cards. Unfortunately I have no references to back up that suspicion. Can anyone confirm whether or not that would help my situation?

Comment: Perhaps [this thread on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2714998) can give some explanation.

Comment: By the sounds of that thread, there's no reason it shouldn't be working already :/

Comment: Rooting might possibly help you to unlock the phone, but I doubt that it will accomplish anything on its own.  Have you verified that the phone hardware is compatible with the network you want to use?

Comment: According to the T-Mobile support rep (and the TM vendor who sold me the SIM to begin with) the phone should be 100% compatible with their network.